# Should a session table be cleared off from the records after a user logs out?

Tags: mysql, session, architecture, storage

I am using a MySql table to store a session record for the current logged in user. Once the user logs off, I update few fields in the same record and flags(revoked) it that it should not be used again. So for every LogIn a new record is created. This serves my purpose, but it turns out that the table is going to grow huge.

What should be the standard approach for storing  Sessions? Should the ones, which are revoked be stored in a separate table, or should they be deleted or left in the same table?

I consider leaving the data in the same session table. While querying for a particular record, I query with two fields : (idPeople (not unique) and revoked (0 or 1)), for example `SELECT * FROM session WHERE idPeople = "someValue" AND revoked = 0`. and then update the record if needed while the user is, logged in or kogging out. Will the huge size of table affect this? or MySql will handle this? And what are other ramifications for this which I am unable to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it may be a good idea to add a unique field to your table (e.g. `SESSION_ID`, which could be a running auto-increment number), define this field as a unique ID, and use it to quickly find the record to be updated (i.e. `revoke=1`).

Second, this type of table always triggers the question you are asking, and the best answer can only be given after you assess and answer some preliminary questions, for instance:

1. When you wish to check the activities of a user, how far into the past does it make sense to go? One month? One year?
2. What is the longest period that you may wish to keep this information available (even using non routine queries to retrieve?
3. What type of **questions** (queries) I expect to be asked on this table?

One you answer those questions, you can consider the following options:

1. Have a routine process that would run once a day (at midnight or any other time your system can afford it) which would delete rows whose timestamp is older than, say, one month (or any other period suiting your needs), OR
2. Same as above but would first copy those records to an "history" table,
3. Change the structure of your table to a more efficient one, by adding some fields (as suggested above) and indices that would provide good answers for your "SELECT" needs.

Comment: Yes, the problem is there are going to be multiple records with the same field i.e. idPeople (this can't be unique) and I know only this, using which I can query the table.

Comment: That is why I'm suggesting to add a field to the table structure, e.g. Session initialization timestamp. You can set a unique index combining the timestamp and the user and get the record filtering by the user and the latest timestamp (and hence, the search will take place using the index and not the actual table).

Comment: Yes, understood, Thanks !

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, if my answer did help you, I'd appreciate if you mark it as such (click on the "V" to the left of the answer). Thanks.